# How can I read float data from a binary file using R

Tags: r, binary

I know there is no float in R. so How can I read float data from a binary file.
the struct of data in C as follows

```
typedef struct
{
    int date;
    int open;
    int high;
    int low;
    int close;
    float amount;
    int vol;
    int reservation;
} StockData; 

to.read = file(filename, "rb");
line1=readBin(to.read,  "int",8);
```

amount is not the right value. how can I get the right value as float?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your C structure is made of 5 integer values followed by a float and then 2 integers again. So, you can call `readBin` three times:

```
 line1<-c(readBin(to.read,"int",5), 
          readBin(to.read,"double",1,size=4),
          readBin(to.read,"int",2))
```

You handle the `float` value by setting the `size` argument to `4`, since a `float` has a size of 4 bytes (instead of the 8 of a `double`).